Using Command + / Command- changes icon desktop size instead of Internet page size on MacBook macOS
Device: MacBook Pro M1 2020.
Until today I used shortcuts to increase or decrease the page size on the Internet:
Command++ and Command+-
From yesterday these commands started to change the size of the icons on the desktop. If I press them when I'm on the desktop, it's increase and decrease the icons size, overriding my user settings.
I read the answers on this site but no solution (like tdefine another keyboard shortcut to those keys for Finder) worked for me.

Those commands (Command++ and  Command +-) only work as you have described (“…increase or decrease the page size on the Internet…”) in Safari.
If you are in the Finder, those commands ( Command ++ and  Command +-) affect desktop appearance and change the size of the icons on the desktop.
What you are seeing are two different applications (Safari and the Finder) use that same key combination for two different reasons.
